# Cannot deduce non-type template parameter of a function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, template-argument-deduction

This might be something really simple, but I cannot figure out why this code does not compile

```
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t Size, std::size_t Align>
void foo(std::aligned_storage_t<Size, Align>&) {}

int main() {
    auto storage = std::aligned_storage_t<100, 8>{};
    foo(storage);
}
```

(https://wandbox.org/permlink/PdBwAWVh6N9rkTE2)

How can I get this to work? And why does not this compile?

---

The usecase is that `foo()` is a suite of overloads on unrelated types like `aligned_storage_t`, `int`, `double`, etc.  And the `aligned_storage_t` instance represents memory that `foo()` knows how to reinterpret and use.

Comment: [`std::aligned_storage_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) is a type alias for some implementation defined type. You have a non-deduced context thus `Size` and `Align` cannot be deduced. Use `std::aligned_storage` instead.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because `std::aligned_storage_t` is not a class, it's a type alias for some implementation defined type. In fact what you have is:

```
template <std::size_t Size, std::size_t Align>
void foo(typename std::aligned_storage<Size, Align>::type);
```

`Size` and `Align` cannot be deduced from this as it is a non-deduced context. You need to replace both instances of `std::aligned_storage_t` with `std::aligned_storage`. Then if you need the aligned type you would access that with `::type`.

Comment: This does not work for me https://wandbox.org/permlink/vDwsjy2y0iesftab. Also, I don't think the standard makes any guarantees about the presence of a `type` alias within `std::aligned_storage_t`..

Comment: @Curious You need to replace *both* instances with `aligned_storage`. And `type` is guaranteed to be presented AFAIK.

Comment: You can't really use an instance of aligned_storage for anything. So I would need to actually pass an instance of aligned_storage_t to a function if that's what you mean?

Comment: @Curious No, you pass an instance of `aligned_storage` (call it `as`), then you would access `::type` with `typename decltype(as)::type`

Comment: That would work if I needed just the type information used in aligned_storage. But I need access to the memory the aligned_storage_t instance represents. I can't really use that instance of aligned_storage for anything on those lines, for example - to launder(reinterpret_cast) to the desired type.

Comment: @Curious Then assuming you don't need `Size` or `Align`, then you can simply deduce the entire parameter and pass the original `aligned_storage_t`.

Comment: I need to use the fact that I have an aligned_storage_t instance for overload resolution, and would like to avoid going into SFINAE land if I can.. Clarified that in the question

Comment: @Curious Then you would have to pass along some type trait (possibly as an argument) that will allow you to know what kind of type you're passing.

Answer (score 0):

`Size` and `Align` is not deducible with `std::aligned_storage<Size, Align>::type`.

You might use `sizeof`/`alignof` to retrieve (nearly) initial value:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T&)
{
    constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof(T);
    constexpr std::size_t alignment = alignof(T);

    std::cout << size << " "<< alignment << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40815cafac153060) (got size of 104 instead of input 100 due to alignment for your example)